# php date_diff not working with time in h:i A format

Tags: php

I have an existing time in DB in h:i A format Ex: 6.30 AM
I am determining the current time as follows:

```
$datecalc = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$timesnow = $datecalc->format('h:i A'); //09.00 AM
//echo $timesnow;
```

But the following is not working??

```
$interval = date_diff($timesnow, $time_in_DB);
echo $interval; //NO RESULT
```

`$time_in_DB` is also in `h:i A` format.

Why is it not working or am i missing something as a newbie ??

Comment: Can you give us the exact value of `$time_in_DB` you are testing with? `print_r($time_in_DB)` and make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: `date_diff` requires two `DateTime` objects, not strings.

Comment: You also don't need to put `$time_zone` into quotes.

Comment: @ceejayoz print_r($time_in_DB) is 06:00 PM

Comment: @deceze Please could you explain what needs to be done so that $time_in_DB is an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date_diff function accepts date objects not strings
Here is the correct example :

```
$date1=date_create("9:00 AM");
$date2=date_create("6:00 PM");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%h");
```

it will print 9 hours difference

Comment: I tried date_create for time_in_DB only. Let me try both.